# Google maps - We don't have maps at this zoom level for this region

Tags: google-maps

I had a map working perfectly on a domain, then I moved it to a different domain and now all I'm getting is a gray canvas with this error message.

It happens in all browsers, regardless of which part of the map I zoom into, and it's not just my computer because I had two other people test it and it didn't work for them either.

Can someone help with this? I've seen the question asked around the web but no satisfactory responses anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing the location/ w/e directly from "http://maps.google.com/". If it results in the same problem, it's obviously on Googles side which means that you can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Get a JavaScript debugger, such as FireBug or Chrome (under Developer Tools) to see where exactly it bugs out.

With an error description like this it's only guessing (can have several reasons).

I mean, you didn't even provide an URL, so this question is quite theoretical.